# Encoding and Set Password For a .Model File in python

Tags: python, security, encryption, libraries, yolo

I have a YOLO v3 Model and it takes for me a lot of times and work to train it and I want to make it secure.
I've Searching for a very secure way to make it unreadable and inaccessable for other but my code.
is there any possible way to do that?